# Using SQL Table valued parameter with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am using Entity Framework v4.0 in my project to connect to a database. I am in a situation to pass a List as input parameter to a stored procedure and do some manipulations in SP and get back List as SP result. I know table valued parameter is one option. But after some investigation I found it is not possible to use Table Valued parameter in Entity Framework. Is there any other way without using Table Valued Parameter to do it through Entity framework?

Comment: Is there any chance you could upgrade to EF5? [It is supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh859577.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can still pass a TVP to a stored procedure even if you are using entity framework.

Example:

```
// Create metadata records
IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord> sqlDataRecords = new List<SqlDataRecord>();

// Create a list of SqlDataRecord objects from your list of entities here

SqlConnection storeConnection = (SqlConnection)((EntityConnection)ObjectContext.Connection).StoreConnection;
try
{
    using (SqlCommand command = storeConnection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.Connection = storeConnection;
        storeConnection.Open();

        SqlParameter[] sqlParameters = parameters.ToArray();
        command.CommandText = YourStoredProcedureName;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("YourTVPName", SqlDbType.Structured)
                            {
                                Value = sqlDataRecords,
                                TypeName = "dbo.Your_Table_Type"
                            });

        using (DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // Read results
        }
    }
}
finally
{
    storeConnection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thankssss!!!! That helps.... But how to get back the list from Stored Procedure ?? ExecuteReader does it ??

Comment: See here for info on reading the results: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz.aspx