# EntityFramework 5.0 and TVP not working together

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a sproc that accepts tvp as parameter. I tested it and it works fine on db side. Now in my c# project I tried to add that sproc in edmx and getting following error.

> Message    8 The function 'usp_MysprocName' has a parameter 'ParameterNameTVP' at parameter index 0 that has a data type 'table type' which is currently not supported for the target .NET Framework version. The function was excluded.

I upgraded my .net framework from 4.0 to 4.5 and re-installed(so it works with the new .net 4.5) entity framework lib through nuget and still showing this same error.
I found [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/table-valued-function-in-entity-framework5.aspx) entityframework 5.0 is supports table valued functions(I have to use 5.0 version not the latest 6). As far as .net framework I am using the latest. I am not sure why VS is not letting me import or add that new sproc.
Any ideas?

Comment: You can convert your objects to a DataTable using [CopyToDataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189(v=vs.110).aspx) then call the stored procedure with a SqlCommand as shown at [Using TVPs with EF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19545835/using-sql-table-valued-parameter-with-entity-framework)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13601366/entityframework-and-tablevalued-parameter

Answer (score 1):

Entity framework does not support stored procedures with TVP's. However, a Table Valued Function is supported, but its not the same thing. In order to achieve similar results, what I had to do was change the datatype of the parameter and use xml. I then wrote a TVF to read the xml and return a table to join with.

Assuming you pass an xml like:
    <list>
        <id>1</id>
    </list>

```
create function [dbo].[XMLToTable] (@xml xml)
returns table
as
return (
--get the ids from the xml
select Item.value('.', 'int') as id from @xml.nodes('//id') as T(Item)
)
```

and your select will be something like

```
select t.* from MyTable t
inner join dbo.XMLToTable(@myXmlParam) x on x.id = t.id
```

EF will treat this as a string parameter, and you just pass it. This is relatively fast because it uses an Inline Table Valued Function. Unfortunately its a workaround until EF decides to support TVP's.

Please upvote the feature request here:
http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/status/317789

EDIT:
Here is a slightly more complex example of how you can deal with multiple values:

```
declare @xml xml = 
'
<complex>
    <companies>
        <id>123456</id>
        <name>My Company</name>
    </companies>
    <companies>
        <id>147889</id>
        <name>Some Co</name>
    </companies>
</complex>
'

declare @tbl table (id int, name varchar(50))

insert into @tbl values (123456, 'My Company'),
            (147889, 'Some Co'),
            (788545, 'Great Corp')


select * from @tbl co
left join dbo.XMLCompanies(@xml) x on x.id = co.id

create function [dbo].[XMLCompanies] (@xml xml)
returns table
as
return (
--get the ids from the xml
select 
     id=Item.value('./id[1]', 'int')
    ,name=Item.value('./name[1]', 'varchar(50)')
from @xml.nodes('//companies') as T(Item)
)
```

Comment: If you need to convert the objects to an XML string, why not convert them to a DataTable and just call the stored procedure using plain ADO.NET?

Comment: That is another solution, but you lose the benefit of importing and updating your procs through the datamodel. However, the OP may take that into consideration.

Also, EF does provide a way to call procs manually without having to rely on pure ADO.net, but again, you won't be able to import the proc and auto-generate complex types.

Comment: You've already lost the mapping benefits of importing when you had to convert your entities to strings. The only other thing you get from importing is avoiding to write the 5-6 lines needed to call the procedure. The performance benefits of TVPS are more important than the convenience of importing

Comment: Yes, there is a cost to both. The work around for TVPs means less maintainability, but the xml decreases performance only slightly as I have noticed. It depends on the OPs needs. If he can work with the manual calling, he will be able to accomplish the ultimate goal, to use TVPs. However, if he "needs" to import the proc, then there is no way without a work around.