# What is the best way to create a query that makes use of heavy filtering on an Id column?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In my application, I will have to use many dynamic queries where I have to select only certain items filtered by their Id, like :

```
SELECT *
FROM Data
WHERE Id IN (231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 329, 330, 331, 332, 333, 334, 335)
```

I am sure that using `IN` is really not the best way to achieve this in terms and performance and furthermore I cannot know in advance the number of Ids I might want to retrieve, so it might eventually be larger than the limit allowed for a number of items in an `IN` clause...

What would be the best mechanism to implement in order to be able to do this kind of filtering?

I thought of using a staging table to insert the Ids and then use a join with this table when doing the data query but I am not sure about the performance of always deleting and inserting in this staging table, furthermore the Ids list is user-dependant, so User1 might be doing a query with Ids 1-200 while User2 is doing a query with Ids 201-500 at the same time...

Thanks

Comment: try using a temp table instead of a regular staging table.

Comment: From where is this list coming?  Also, in what language are you writing your application?

Comment: How is client of your sql server?

Comment: c# and the ids list is depending on some user inputs

Comment: The keywords are `Table-Valued Parameters` and `SqlDbType.Structured`

Comment: so a user is going to type a list of several hundred IDs?

Comment: I often compare the PK against an array of id's in this way without any trouble. How many id's are you really targeting?

Comment: @DanBracuk, `ids list is depending on some user inputs` The keyword is **depending**.

Comment: @MattiasÅslund might be a couple thousands

Comment: @HamletHakobyan your hints point to an interesting solution...I will look into more information about how to properly use those keywords

Comment: Good luck! One interesting point: Is the Id-s sequential as described in OP?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan They might be but it is not guaranteed and can also be non-sequential. If I end up using this and would like me to accept your answer, please leave an answer below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is applicable, you can create and use the `Table-Valued Parameters`. First, define the `User-Defined Table Types` on your server, then, on the client side, create the parameter of type `SqlDbType.Structured` set the `TypeName` property of your parameter to the `User-Defined Table Types` name and use one of the supported type data for populating the `table-valued parameter`.

For more information see the `MSDN` article [Table-Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: This is great, is there a similar solution if the context I am in does not allow the use of stored procedures? (e.g. Entity Framework)

Comment: In `EF` you can use list directly in your `LINQ` the provider will generate the `IN clause`.

Comment: but isn't using `IN` kinda bad? (performance-wise and eventually hitting the limit of parameters allowed in a `IN` clause)

Comment: Why you think that `IN` is bad? If you have index on filed `IN` produces index seek depending on statistic.

Comment: @ibiza see here regarding EF and TVP/Stored proc: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19545835/using-sql-table-valued-parameter-with-entity-framework

Comment: @MattiasÅslund, Why, what is the win?

Comment: @Hamlet It is just a friendly reference, since he claimed EF couldnt do stored procs

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use CTEs ? like

```
;WITH filter AS 
(
   SELECT ID FROM Somwhere
)

SELECT * FROM filter 
JOIN data ON filter.id = data.id

--Lets choose now next filter

;WITH filter AS
(
    SELECT Id FROM newCriteria
)
```

--Go on...

And in case of big set of ids maybe you will have chance to declare some @MinID, @MaxID and then use just

```
Where ID Between @MinID AND @MaxID
```

Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

Often in these forumns,  the questioner implies that he is doing something like this.

```
query 1
select id 
from table1
where whatever
```

and then

```
query 2
select *
from table2
where id in (the list from table 1)
```

with both tables in the same database.  In other words, the questioner did not know how to join tables.

That's probably not the case here, because @ibiza mentions joining tables in his last paragraph.   That would suggest that there is more than one database at play.  If they are on the same server, a better way to approach this situation is to get the appropriate permissions and qualify your tables with the database names.  Something like this:

```
from database1.schemaname.tablename t1 join database2.schemaname.tablename t2
on t1.id = t2.id
```

However, the two databases might not be on the same server.  If that's the case, my favourite method is to get linked servers set up.  Then use openquery to get the data from the remote server into a temporary table on the current server.  You can then join to the temporary table.  I would do this in a stored procedure.

As a last resort, you can try to use application code to break the long list into a series of shorter lists.  Then you loop through these shorter lists and once you are done, you assemble your final results.  However, this is messy, which is why it's the last resort.